# Where should I ask this question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Should I configure router as bridge?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53259/should-i-configure-router-as-bridge)

I don't know where is the right place to ask it. ¿Super User, or there is a more specific stackexchange site about networking?

This is an enterprise network, and I'm on charge of this router, even if it is a consumer-grade device.

I'm not in charge of the enterprise network, but the network manager prefers to delegate on me any small issue.

Comment: Ron Maupin already gave you a perfect explanation. If you do not control the router there is no suitable StackExchange site, where you can ask that question.